# HTML5 Drag and Drop: Load text file in a textbox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow users to drag and drop (or select) a file from their computer and load it into a textbox with JavaScript.

Is it possible to load a local file with JavaScript into a textbox? If yes, then how?

Comment: Isn't this possible without Uploading the file to server maybe with `FileReader()`

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://html5demos.com/file-api) tweaked for text files?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think everything you would want for HTML5 is included in [remy/html5demos](https://github.com/remy/html5demos) on github.

As an example, I modified http://html5demos.com/file-api to accept text files and display them in the browser.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/DqcUg/).

**Edit**
Relevant script:

```
// modified from http://html5demos.com/file-api
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
    state = document.getElementById('status');

if (typeof window.FileReader === 'undefined') {
    state.className = 'fail';
} else {
    state.className = 'success';
    state.innerHTML = 'File API & FileReader available';
}

holder.ondragover = function() {
    this.className = 'hover';
    return false;
};
holder.ondragend = function() {
    this.className = '';
    return false;
};
holder.ondrop = function(e) {
    this.className = '';
    e.preventDefault();

    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        console.log(event.target);
        holder.innerText = event.target.result;
    };
    console.log(file);
    reader.readAsText(file);

    return false;
};​
```

Comment: The `ondragend` event wasn't working on chrome 56, on my mac. I had to change it to `onmouseleave`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `HTML5 File API`: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

The spec also has a good example to get an idea of how it works:

http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#introduction

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help most of you:

**Events fired on the draggable target (the source element):**

ondragstart - occurs when the user starts to drag an element

ondrag - occurs when an element is being dragged

ondragend - occurs when the user has finished dragging the element

**Events fired on the drop target:**

ondragenter - occurs when the dragged element enters the drop target

ondragover - occurs when the dragged element is over the drop target

ondragleave - occurs when the dragged element leaves the drop target

ondrop - occurs when the dragged element is dropped on the drop target